# Question about proof of $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr C$, $\mathscr C \Rightarrow \mathscr D$ $\vdash$ $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr D$

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I have some doubts about the following proof of  $ \mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr C$, $\mathscr C \Rightarrow \mathscr D$ $\vdash$ $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr D$. The proof is done in axiomatic theory L.

Proof$:\\1.\text{ }\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr C
       \\2. \text{ } \text{ }\mathscr C \Rightarrow \mathscr D
       \\3. \text{ } \mathscr B
       \\4. \text{ } \mathscr C
       \\5. \text{ } \mathscr D$

Where $1.\text{ } 2.\text{ } 3.$ are hypothesis, $4.$ comes from $1.\text{ } 3$ and modus ponens(MP) and lastly $5.$ comes from $2.\text{ } 4$ and MP. Thus $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr C$, $\mathscr C \Rightarrow \mathscr D$, $\mathscr B$ $\vdash$ $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr D$, so by deduction theorem $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr C$, $\mathscr C \Rightarrow \mathscr D$ $\vdash$ $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr D$.

The question is why it is assumed that $\mathscr B$ is a hypothesis but we are proving both $\mathscr C$ and $\mathscr D$? Why can't we assume both $\mathscr B$, $\mathscr C$, $\mathscr D$? In general when are we allowed to assume $\mathscr B$? The textbook I use is Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic and the proof comes from this book from page 31 of the sixth edition.

Comment: The is an error in the formula after the derivation.

Comment: If we assume also D, we have not proved that D is consequence of the premises 1-3.

Comment: Okay, but why can't we assume $\mathscr C$?

Comment: Because assuming B it is enough to deduce C and then D.

Comment: That's true but I find it strange that author prefers to prove $\mathscr C$ rather than saying that $\mathscr C$ can also be assumed.

Comment: You should've said $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr C, \mathscr C \Rightarrow \mathscr D, \mathscr B\vdash\mathscr D$, which then implies that $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr C, \mathscr C \Rightarrow \mathscr D\vdash\mathscr B\Rightarrow \mathscr D$ by Deduction theorem.

Comment: Also, you want to use Deduction theorem to prove $\mathscr B\Rightarrow\mathscr D$ so you want to bring it first to the previous form (which as I said before is $\mathscr B \Rightarrow \mathscr C, \mathscr C \Rightarrow \mathscr D, \mathscr B\vdash\mathscr D$), for which you need to assume $\mathscr B$ (and conclude $\mathscr D$).

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Do we assume that $\mathscr B$ is a theorem and also $\mathscr C$, $\mathscr D$ are theorems too?

Comment: Or do we just assume that $\mathscr B$,$\mathscr C$, $\mathscr D$ are wfs but then as we assume $\mathscr B$ in step $3.$ is it still wfs or theorem?

Comment: If you assumed $C$ instead of proving it, your argument would show $B\to C, C\to D, B, C\vdash D$. The deduction theorem would then give you $B\to C, C\to D, B\vdash C\to D$, and another application of the deduction theorem would give $B\to C, C\to D\vdash B\to(C\to D)$. All those statements are correct, and so are some others that you'd get by other applications of the deduction theorem,. But none of them is the result you're asked to prove.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume some formula $A$ and are able to derive another formula $B$ under that assumption, then you are justified in concluding $A \to B$ which effectively states "*if* $A$ is true, *then* $B$ is true." This is actually an application of an inference rule known as *conditional proof*.

This is why the proof proceeds by assuming $\mathscr B$ and then deriving $\mathscr D$ via repeated application of Modus Ponens. The conditional proof is being applied to derive the conditional $\mathscr B \to \mathscr D$ where $\mathscr B$ is the antecedent and $\mathscr D$ is the consequent.

Note the conditional proof does not assert the assumption $\mathscr B$ is in fact true. It only states that $\mathscr D$ is true if the assumption $\mathscr B$ happens to be true.